# Oracle: Query to determine storage that is consumed from a tablespace by one or multiple schema(s)?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, tablespace

In Oracle 12c, I'm trying to find an Oracle SQL query that may determine how much total storage was consumed from a particular tablespace by one schema or multiple schemas.

Note: I don't need to know the available space, just the space consumed by those particular schemas together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find out free space on tablespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672126/find-out-free-space-on-tablespace)

Comment: @Tejash It does not. I need to know how much space that a schema or schemas have taken. Not the available space of a tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data you need is in DBA_SEGMENTS.  For example, you could list all the schemas with objects in the 'USERS' tablespace as follows:

```
select tablespace_name, owner
, round(sum(bytes) / (1024*1024) , 1) mb_used_in_ts
from dba_segments
where 1=1
  and tablespace_name = 'USERS'
group by tablespace_name, owner
;
```

The following query does a little more than you asked, but you should find it useful:

```
with ts_name as
(
select 'DEFAULT' tablespace_type
, DEFAULT_TABLESPACE tablespace_name
from dba_users where username = upper(:username)
union
select 'INDEX'  tablespace_type
, substr(default_tablespace, 1, instr(default_tablespace, '_DATA'))||'INDEX' tablespace_name
from dba_users where username = upper(:username)
union
select 'Data?'  tablespace_type
, upper(:username) || '_DATA' tablespace_name
from dual 
union
select 'Index?'  tablespace_type
, upper(:username) || '_INDEX' tablespace_name
from dual 
union
select ':tablespace input'  tablespace_type
,  upper(:tablespace)  tablespace_name
from dual 
union
select ':tablespace2 input'  tablespace_type
,  upper(:tablespace2)   tablespace_name
from dual 
)
SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') date_checked
, df.tablespace_name "Tablespace"
, nvl(totalusedspace, 0) "Used MB"
, nvl((df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace), df.totalspace) "Free MB"
, df.totalspace "Total MB"
, nvl(ROUND (100 * ((df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace) / df.totalspace)), 100) "Pct. Free"
, (select SEGMENT_SPACE_MANAGEMENT 
   from dba_tablespaces a
  where a.tablespace_name = df.tablespace_name) SEGMENT_SPACE_MANAGEMENT
FROM (SELECT   tablespace_name, ROUND (SUM (BYTES) / (1024*1024)) totalspace
            FROM dba_data_files
        GROUP BY tablespace_name) df,
       (SELECT   ROUND (SUM (BYTES) / (1024 * 1024)) totalusedspace,
                 tablespace_name
            FROM dba_segments
        GROUP BY tablespace_name) tu
 WHERE df.tablespace_name = tu.tablespace_name (+)
   AND df.tablespace_name in (select tablespace_name from ts_name) 
order by 6 
;
```

Comment: Not sure if I completely understood this query correctly, but I was looking to see if I could get storage information on one or more schemas from a single tablespace, not multiple tablespaces.

Comment: @Phillip I believe you want to see who all uses a tablespace and how much they use.  See edit to original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dba_segments` view, e.g.:

```
select owner, sum(bytes)
from dba_segments
where tablespace_name = 'MYTABLESPACE'
group by owner
order by sum(bytes) desc;
```

The `owner` column is the schema name that owns the objects that have allocated some storage space.

You can further break down the results by object type (e.g. TABLE, INDEX) as well:

```
select segment_type, sum(bytes)
from dba_segments
where tablespace_name = 'MYTABLESPACE'
and owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
group by segment_type
order by sum(bytes) desc;
```

And further by object name:

```
select segment_name, sum(bytes)
from dba_segments
where tablespace_name = 'MYTABLESPACE'
and owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
and segment_type = 'TABLE'
group by segment_name
order by sum(bytes) desc;
```